# Debugging NuGet being run as part of VS solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

He have configured NuGet to run as part of the solution, but we have issues with configuration. It seems to only pick the local configuration file from `%APPDATA%\...`, which is the opposite to what we want it to do (use the config from the version control system, stored with the code). How can I figure out what exactly NuGet is doing when run during the build in Visual Studio? Is there an option for a verbose run, so that it dumps all the paths that it is using, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to build the solution using msbuild:

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" abcd.sln  /t:Build /property:Configuration=Release /v:diag
```